# Expand macro value in the variable name

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have

```
#define MACRO foo

#define Code(m) \
    m##Bar

Code(MACRO)
```

I would like this to be resolved as fooBar, but it is resolved as MACROBar.

What I need to change the macro to be resolved by its value, not its name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is secondary function-like macro, that expands `m` preprocessing token into `foo`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO foo

#define CodeReal(m) \
    m##Bar

#define Code(m) CodeReal(m)

int main(void)
{
    int Code(MACRO) = 0;

    printf("%d\n", fooBar);

    return 0;
}
```

As pointed in [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267067/expand-macro-value-in-the-variable-name#comment44890450_28267150) you need it because macro's arguments, that are subject to `##` operator are not evaluated to their values (i.e. replacements). This code above is a common remedy to such issue.

Comment: And you need it because ["If an argument is stringified or concatenated, the prescan does not occur."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan)